# Why we need the `Asyncio.sleep` to start the loop?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

In this [document of Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel), we can see it use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` to delay 1 second and then cancel the task.

And I try to change it to `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, it works well too.

But when I try to delete `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, the program seems wouldn't enter the func `cancel_me`. So it just appear `main(): cancel_me is cancelled now` in the cli.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` coroutines aren't executed by themselves, they're executed by [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#event-loop).

Event loop receives control on `asyncio.run` and starts to execute some coroutine. When execution flow reaches something blocking like `await asyncio.sleep()` or `await future` it return control back to event loop. It allows event loop to start or resume execution of something else.

Take a look at example and picture [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#example-chain-coroutines) to see it on simple example.

---

In the [example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) about `cancel()` following happen:

1. `await asyncio.sleep(0)` as well as `1` will return control to event loop
2. Event loop will start to execute `cancel_me()`
3. `cancel_me()` eventually will stumble on something blocking and return control back to event loop
4. Event loop will resume execution of `main()`
5. `main()` will mark task to be cancelled with `task.cancel()` and await it cancelled with `await task`

If you however don't have `asyncio.sleep()` on step one, execution flow won't even reach `cancel_me()` because event loop never received control between tasks creation and task cancellation. When event loop reaches `await task` it sees task was never started and mark for cancellation: there's no sense to start it now.