# Converting small functions to coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I feel like there is a gap in my understanding of async IO: **is there a benefit to wrapping small functions into coroutines, within the scope of larger coroutines?**  Is there a benefit to this in signaling the event loop correctly?  Does the extent of this benefit depend on whether the wrapped function is IO or CPU-bound?

Example: I have a coroutine, `download()`, which:

1. Downloads JSON-serialized bytes from an HTTP endpoint via `aiohttp`.
2. Compresses those bytes via [`bz2.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html#one-shot-de-compression) - which is **not in itself awaitable**
3. Writes the compressed bytes to S3 via [`aioboto3`](https://aioboto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

So parts 1 & 3 use predefined coroutines from those libraries; part 2 does not, by default.

Dumbed-down example:

```
import bz2
import io
import aiohttp
import aioboto3

async def download(endpoint, bucket_name, key):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.request("GET", endpoint, raise_for_status=True) as resp:
            raw = await resp.read()  # payload (bytes)
            # Yikes - isn't it bad to throw a synchronous call into the middle
            # of a coroutine?
            comp = bz2.compress(raw)
            async with (
                aioboto3.session.Session()
                .resource('s3')
                .Bucket(bucket_name)
            ) as bucket:
                await bucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(comp), key)
```

As hinted by the comment above, my understanding has always been that throwing a synchronous function like `bz2.compress()` into a coroutine can mess with it.  (Even if `bz2.compress()` is probably more IO-bound than CPU-bound.)

So, is there generally any benefit to this type of boilerplate?

```
async def compress(*args, **kwargs):
    return bz2.compress(*args, **kwargs)
```

(And now `comp = await compress(raw)` within `download()`.)

Wa-la, this is now an awaitable coroutine, because a sole `return` is valid in a native coroutine.  Is there a case to be made for using this?

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438300/7954504), I've heard justification for randomly throwing in `asyncio.sleep(0)` in a similar manner - just to single back up to the event loop that the calling coroutine wants a break.  Is this right?

Comment: Your question about small coroutines is interesting but maybe you will have more benefit from running synchronous function [in executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)?

Comment: Someone can probably make an answer out of this: just putting a function in a coroutine doesn't make it asynchronous: it will still block.  As @sanyash mentions, placing it in an executor will help to run it in another thread if you have something else to do in the meantime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, is there generally any benefit to this type of boilerplate?

```
async def compress(*args, **kwargs):
    return bz2.compress(*args, **kwargs)
```

There is no benefit to it whatsoever. Contrary to expectations, adding an `await` [doesn't guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816319/1600898) that the control will be passed to the event loop - that will happen only if the awaited coroutine actually suspends. Since `compress` doesn't await anything, it will never suspend, so it's a coroutine in name only.

Note that adding `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in coroutines does not solve the problem; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55819648/1600898) for a more detailed discussion. If you need to run a blocking function, use [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor):

```
async def compress(*args, **kwargs):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: bz2.compress(*args, **kwargs))
```

Answer (score 2):

Coroutines allow you to run something concurrently, *not* in parallel. They allow for a *single-threaded cooperative* multitasking. This makes sense in two cases:

- You need to produce results in lockstep, like two generators would.
- You want something useful be done while another coroutine is waiting for I/O.

Things like http requests or disk I/O would allow other coroutines to run while they are waiting for completion of an operation.

`bz2.compress()` is synchronous <s>and, *I suppose,* does not release GIL</s> [but does release GIL](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0353b4eaaf451ad463ce7eb3074f6b62d332f401/Modules/_bz2module.c#L180) while it is running. <s>This means that no meaningful work can be done while it's running.</s> That is, other coroutines would not run during its invocation, though other threads would.

If you anticipate a *large* amount of data to compress, so large that the overhead of running a coroutine is small in comparison, you can use `bz2.BZ2Compressor` and feed it with data in reasonably small blocks (like 128KB), write the result to a stream (S3 supports streaming, or you can use StringIO), and [`await asyncio.sleep(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep) between compressing blocks to yield control.

This will allow other coroutines to also run concurrently with your compression coroutine. Possibly async S3 upload will be occurring in parallel at the socket level, too, while your coroutine would be inactive.

BTW making your compressor explicitly an [async generator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) can be a simpler way to express the same idea.

Comment: The part about feeding smaller blocks to `bz2.BZ2Compressor` makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.  I also think that I can (possibly) feed the `resp` itself, seeing that it is buffer-lik, to `compress()`.

Comment: bz2 does release the gil, so could be effectively used in another thread [ref: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0353b4eaaf451ad463ce7eb3074f6b62d332f401/Modules/_bz2module.c#L180 ]

Comment: @BradSolomon: I upvoted the other answer, which is likely a better solution.

Comment: @Max would you say there is still some effectiveness to chunking the compress/decompress routine?  https://pastebin.com/523W9zXU

Comment: @BradSolomon You'd have to measure it, but assuming you're on a multi core system, and your blocks are big enough that the thread coordination is worth it, the separate thread will be faster.